# Ionic2 - How to import css files for a page component

Tags: ionic2

I have to import some stylesheets residing inside node_modules (bootstrap.css from node_modules, etc).
I tried by

- adding styleUrls inside @Page,
- putting the styles in the .scss file inside the page component folder,
- and finally putting the styles inside the template file itself by creating new style tag... all with no luck, i.e the required styles are not getting applied on tags with appropriate classes.

How to do this ?

> PN: I had imported the page scss for my components in app.core.scs.
>   Anyways, I think putting bootstrap.min.css inside page scss is not a
>   good way

Comment: This may or may not help but if you add the styles into a .scss file you still need to import the file into app.core.scss via the @import decorator. Ionic will use app.core.scss and all .scss file imported into it when building the project. but they must be imported

Comment: If your talking about global styles applied to your whole app that come from node_modules, you just want to include these as regular stylesheets in your index.html.  Is there a reason you don't want to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@import "../pages/yourpage/yourpage"
```

Add this line in **app/themes/app.core.scss** and rebuild. Of course change **yourpage** expression.

Answer (score 9):

Adding the above import doesn't seem to work in the latest version of Ionic2 (ionic -version = 2.1.4) that I installed on 10/25/16.  There is no longer an `app.core.scss` file in newly created projects.  But rather just `variables.scss` in `src/app/theme`.

There is a file `app.scss` in `src/app` that says it's for global SASS and importing other files, but adding an import for another page does not seem to make a difference.

I have a page `/src/app/pages/about`, in which I have `about.ts` that has `styleUrls: ['about.scss']`.  The file `about.scss` is in the same directory.  Putting `@import "../pages/about/about"`; at the bottom of that file makes no difference.

UPDATE:

I have finally got it to work with this in `about.ts`:

`styleUrls: ['/pages/about/about.scss']`

I'm not sure if this is the best way yet, but it works for now.

Comment: Does the word "this" at the very beginning of your post refer to [kipcakbegi's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37503232/3982001)? Then you should remember that this is a Q&A site, not a forum. Answers are ordered based on their score. If your answer had a higher score, it would show up first, and then, to anyone reading it, "this" would make no sense. So please [edit] your answer and add a link to the post you refer to, as I have done. Thank you!

Comment: You are really a life saviour .I was searching whole day but could not able to find the line and any doc mentioned about this change.